# Windows form using DAL BLL functions are not show for an object

Tags: c#, winforms, data-access-layer

My EmployeeDB class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Test
{
    public class EmployeeDB
    {
        private string connectionString;

        public EmployeeDB()
        {
            //my connectionstring info
        }

        public int CountEmployees()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CountEmployees", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                // Replace the error with something less specific.
                // You could also log the error now.
                throw new ApplicationException("Data error.");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        public List<EmployeeDetails> GetEmployees()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllEmployees", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Create a collection for all the employee records.
            List<EmployeeDetails> employees = new List<EmployeeDetails>();

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails(
                        (int)reader["EmployeeID"], (string)reader["FirstName"],
                        (string)reader["LastName"], (string)reader["TitleOfCourtesy"]);
                    employees.Add(emp);
                }
                reader.Close();

                return employees;
            }
            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                // Replace the error with something less specific.
                // You could also log the error now.
                throw new ApplicationException("Data error.");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My employeeDetails class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Test
{
    public class EmployeeDetails
    {
private int employeeID;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string titleOfCourtesy;

        public int EmployeeID
        {
            get {return employeeID;}
            set {employeeID = value;}
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get {return firstName;}
            set {firstName = value;}
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get {return lastName;}
            set {lastName = value;}
        }
        public string TitleOfCourtesy
        {
            get {return titleOfCourtesy;}
            set {titleOfCourtesy = value;}
        }

        public EmployeeDetails(int employeeID, string firstName, string lastName,
            string titleOfCourtesy)
        {
            this.employeeID = employeeID;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.titleOfCourtesy = titleOfCourtesy;
        }

        public EmployeeDetails(){}

    }
}
```

When I build the class library and add the reference to my windows form project.

Here is a screenshot of my main form that the class shows up; however, there are no methods.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind to a DataGrid:

1. Add a BindingSource (bindingSource) to the form
2. Set the DataSource property of the DataGrid to bindingSource
3. Set the DataSource property of the bindingSource to the result of your GetEmployees()

If you have the following implementation for your library like:

```
public interface IDataOperation
{
    List<Employee> GetEmployees();
}

public class DataOperation : IDataOperation
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees(){}
}
```

Your implementation should look like:

```
IDataOperation dataOperation = new DataOperation();

var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
dataGrid.DataSource = bindingSource;
bindingSource.DataSource = dataOperation.GetEmployees();
```

Or, you could just simply set the DataSource property of your DataGrid to the result of GetEmployees() programatically without using BindingSource:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = dataOperation.GetEmployees();
```

EDIT: In your screenshot, you should instantiate your EmployeeDB before using it like the code below:

```
Test.EmployeeDB employeeDB = new Test.EmployeeDB();
dataGrid.DataSource = employeeDB.GetEmployees(); // assuming you have a dataGrid control
```

Comment: Even though I added the reference to my DLL and all my classes are PUBLIC is there any reason why my method would not be exposed when I type bll.????? nothing shows

Comment: Yes, there is. If your DataOperation inherits from an interface and that interface does not declare a contract List<Employees> GetEmployees(), when you implicitly cast your DataOperation(e.g. IDataOperation dataOperation = new DataOperation()), you won't see the method GetEmployees() unless you cast dataOperation and perform operation like this: 

((DataOperation)dataOperation).GetEmployees();

Comment: Thanks for all your help. From what I gather seems as if I am missing the interface class is this required with windows form in order to expose methods of a DLL as in asp.net webforms this was not the case? But once I added a interface class my method was there.

Comment: @Tim you can do without it, but it is a good practice to use interface  to prevent tight coupling in your application.

Comment: I might have to open a new question then because for the life of me I can not figure out why my design is not allowing me to show the methods. I will edit this question to show you my exact classes in few minutes if you can check it out if not I understand. THanks

Comment: oh ok, before you use your library, you need to create an instance: EmployeeDB employeeDB = new EmployeeDB(); then you can use the created instance as: employeeDB.GetEmployees(); hope this helps.